# String expansion: spaces are removed

Tags: expansion, latex3

I have a LaTeX3 string containing something like `Hello \macro`, and I’d like to expand it into another string, so that if `\macro` is defined as `Alice`, then the resulting should be `Hello Alice`. I tried to do it using a mix of rescan and `:x`, but it strips the spaces. Do you know what I am doing wrong? It it because the space is ignored by LaTeX3’s evaluation? If so, can I somehow evaluate it using the LaTeX2 standards?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defMyString}{m}{
  \str_set:Nn \l_mystr_str {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defMyString{Hello \macro}

\def\macro{Alice}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_new_tl  {} {\l_mystr_str}
\str_set:Nx \l_new_str {\l_new_tl }
\l_new_str
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are rescanning inside `\ExplSyntaxOn`, where spaces are ignored.  Make a document command with that, and use it outside `\ExplSyntaxOn/Off`

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Feel free to write an answer, I’ll add one meanwhile but I can remove mine

Comment: Yours is fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the first argument to `\tl_set_rescan:nn`, that's thought for such purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defMyString}{m}{
  \str_set:Nn \l_mystr_str {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defMyString{Hello \macro}

\def\macro{Alice}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_new_tl  { \char_set_catcode_space:N \ } {\l_mystr_str}
\str_set:Nx \l_new_str {\l_new_tl }
\l_new_str
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Even better for your application should be to select the appropriate catcode table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defMyString}{m}{
  \str_set:Nn \l_mystr_str {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defMyString{Hello \macro}

\def\macro{Alice}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_new_tl  { \cctab_select:N \c_document_cctab } {\l_mystr_str}
\str_set:Nx \l_new_str {\l_new_tl }
\l_new_str
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Phelype’s comment, I need to put the rescan in a command called outside of the `\ExplSyntax…` segment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defMyString}{m}{
  \str_set:Nn \l_mystr_str {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defMyString{Hello \macro}

\def\macro{Alice}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{}{
  \tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_new_tl  {} {\l_mystr_str}
  \str_set:Nx \l_new_str {\l_new_tl }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\test

\ExplSyntaxOn
\l_new_str
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```